# Limit of trigonometrical function $\sin(\pi x)/{(1-x)}$ as $x\to1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have the following function:
$$\lim_{x\to1} {\sin(\pi x)\over{1-x}}.$$

I need to calculate the limit, although I can't use here L'Hôpital's rule.
I have a clue that says to use a correct mathematical placement.

Can you please advise only what the placement should be?

I've tried several placements but couldn't find the correct one.

Thank you all.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle{\frac{\sin (\pi x)}{x-1}=-\frac{\sin (\pi (x-1))}{x-1}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to compute the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}.$$

Notice first that, using the sine sum formula, we have that

$$\sin(\pi x)=\sin(\pi x-\pi+\pi)=\sin(\pi x-\pi)\underbrace{\cos(\pi)}_{=-1}+\cos(\pi x-\pi)\underbrace{\sin(\pi)}_{=0}=-\sin(\pi x-\pi).$$

We can thus rewrite

$$\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}=-\pi\frac{\sin(\pi x-\pi)}{\pi x-\pi}.$$

Now as $\pi x-\pi\to 0$ as $x\to 1$, we can use the standard limit

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$$

to get that

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-1}=-\pi\left(\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi x-\pi)}{\pi x-\pi}\right)=-\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you, this was the correct way after my lecturer published the solution. !

Answer (score 2):

You write $$\frac{\sin \pi x}{1-x}=-\pi\times\frac{\sin \pi (x-1)}{\pi(x-1)}$$ and you know that the $\lim _{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$. Hence $\lim \limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin \pi (x-1)}{\pi(x-1)}=1.$ So the answer should be $-\pi$.

Comment: But $\pi x\not\to0$ in this case. You need to also use $\sin y=\sin(\pi-y)$.

Comment: This doesn't work as the limit is as $x\to 1$, **not** as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @J.G., Oh of course. I did not notice that.

Comment: The answer is still incorrect; there is a missing minus sign, the answer should be $-\pi$.

Comment: The sign of the first equation is incorrect, and it carries through to the final result.

Comment: @Lorago, Thanks for pointing out my mistake! I thought that originally function was $\sin (\pi x)/(x-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use
$$\pi x = \pi x + \pi - \pi = \pi(x-1) + \pi $$

and with $t = \pi(x-1)$ if $x\to 1$ then $t \to 0$